# Initialized HashSet Array in Java

Tags: java, collections, initialization

I'm having a problem initializing array of HashSet

```
  int N = 100;
  HashSet<Integer> []array = new HashSet[N]; 
  for (HashSet<Integer> set:array){
    set = new HashSet<Integer>();
  }
```

But the array contains only null. (Also error when HashSet []array = .... )

But when running with:

```
   for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
      array[i] = new HashSet<Integer>();
   }
```

All is well.

Why does the first code isn't working? Is it my mistake?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You never actually assign initialized instances to elements of the array. Instead you iterate over the elements of the array with a variable that gets assigned to a new object in your loop, then is never used. In a case like this the enhanced for...each syntax is not appropriate, use the traditional for loop instead.

Comment: Thanks!! I think I understood that, it even makes sense now :)

Comment: @AL - the variable in the for...each loop is a locally scoped reference that is ***not*** the same as the one actually stored in the array (which actually doesn't exist since the array contains nothing but nulls). Assigning it a value only has meaning within the for...each loop, but doesn't actually change the array.

Comment: Yes, I was respond to the first post at the beginning. Thank you very much for your (you and MouseEvent) details explanation. The answers were very good and focused me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

two 'for' is different in Java, look the java code & bytecode ..
Example:

```
public class T{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            String[] data = new String[10];
            System.out.print("");
            for(String str:data){
                str="1";
            }   
            System.out.print("");
            for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                data[i]="1";
            }
        }
    }

$>javac -classpath . T.java
$>javap -c T


Compiled from "T.java"
public class T extends java.lang.Object{
public T();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   bipush  10
   2:   anewarray   #2; //class java/lang/String
   5:   astore_1
   6:   getstatic   #3; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   9:   ldc #4; //String 
   11:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/io/PrintStream.print:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   14:  aload_1
   15:  astore_2
   16:  aload_2
   17:  arraylength
   18:  istore_3
   19:  iconst_0
   20:  istore  4
   22:  iload   4
   24:  iload_3
   25:  if_icmpge   44
   28:  aload_2
   29:  iload   4
   31:  aaload
   32:  astore  5
   34:  ldc #6; //String 1
   36:  astore  5
   38:  iinc    4, 1
   41:  goto    22
   44:  getstatic   #3; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   47:  ldc #4; //String 
   49:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/io/PrintStream.print:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   52:  iconst_0
   53:  istore_2
   54:  iload_2
   55:  aload_1
   56:  arraylength
   57:  if_icmpge   71
   60:  aload_1
   61:  iload_2
   62:  ldc #6; //String 1
   64:  aastore
   65:  iinc    2, 1
   68:  goto    54
   71:  return

}
```

from line 25--44 and line 57--71:
aload : Retrieves an object reference from a local variable and pushes it onto the operand stack.
aaload : Retrieves an object reference from an array of objects and places it on the stack.

astore : Take object or  reference  store to local variable.
aastore : Take  reference type value store to array.

so,first can't store array , didn't using initializing array.

Answer (score 0):

An `enhanced for loop`, does not use the actual instances in the array( and as well, collection), but rather copies them in the loop control variable.

This should not be a problem with non-null values, since they point to the same object. Problems arise, if the values are null, and re-assigning values to the control variable, would not change the actual value. So in this case, always use regular `for` loops.

The same would be true, to arrays of primitive types, since coping them, and changing the copied variable, will not affect the original variable.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use new Set[n] instead of new HashSet[n] , to get it working

```
Set<Integer>[] list = new Set[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  list[i] = new HashSet<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array that contains HashSet
so, you need to initialize the array and then initialize the HashSet
which I have provided in the below code

```
 int N = 100;
Set<Integer>[] array = new Set[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        array[i] = new HashSet<Integer>();
    }
```